# Create a Filter for Postfix on Virtual Mails

Tags: postfix, filter

This is what I am trying to do:

I have a server using Postfix on a Ubuntu precise 64bits and I have a table list of emails in /etc/postfix/virtual, like this:

```
artz@mydomain.com  artz@gmail.com
artz2@mydomain.com artz@yahoo.com
```

Now I want to put a filter that get all mails sent and add some prefix to the subject or add something else to the end of the mail.

In the file /etc/postfix/master.cf I put:

```
filter    unix  -       n       n       -       10      pipe
  flags=Rq user=filter argv=/home/filter/filtro.php -f ${sender} -- ${recipient}
```

I created the user filter and put the file /home/filter/filtro.php:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
$myFile = "/home/filter/testFile.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a');
fwrite($fh, "\n-----------------------\n");
fwrite($fh, json_encode($_SERVER['argv']) );
?>
```

It was just to see if it´s working. But it´s not.
Anyone can see a light for my problem?

Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? It will be better if u can say what u want exactly.

Comment: Ok. Right. I didnt do anything inside filtro.php because I wanted to see if this filter would work, but what I want to do is add something like [artz@mydomain.com] before the subject text and add a text at the end of the content message saying "This message was sent to artz@mydomain.com."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `mimedefang` configured as `smtpd_milter` with postfix. It can change/add/delete headers (`action_change_header`/`action_insert_header`/`action_delete_header`) and append text (`append_text_boilerplate`) to the mails. More info [here](http://www.mickeyhill.com/mimedefang-howto/)